# How to remove an animation from JavaScript and how change background color ? (two separate questions)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two issues. First, I have an animation feature I’m trying to change in the class of a “popup” that codes a gallery section of a website. When users load the page, a square image and background begin to expand, or grow, from a scale of zero in the center of the page to a 100 VIEWPORT HEIGHT (VH) and 100 VIEWPORT WIDTH (VW). In other words, the image “pops up” from center page and fills the screen with an inch of padding for the background. I don’t want the page to open this way. I want the image to open without animation (i.e. growing effect) and display instantly at 100VH and 100VW.

The second issue is this. I have six images in the gallery that users are able to horizontally scroll through using arrow buttons. Right now, the background color is set to one color so as you scroll, each image displays against the same background color. I want the background color to be different for each image as users scroll through them.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Popup</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        

        <div class="top-bar">
            <p class="image-name">img1.png</p>
            <span class="close-btn">
                <img src="Graphics/gallery_icon.svg" width="50px" class="close">
            </span>
        </div>
    
        <button class="arrow-btn left-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
        <button class="arrow-btn right-arrow"><img src="img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
    
        <img src="img/img1.png" class="large-image" alt="">
    
        <h1 class="index">01</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="image">
            
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img2.png" alt="" class="image">
            <div class="bk"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img3.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img4.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img5.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <img src="img/img6.png" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff7a2d;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}



.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}




.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: turquoise;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name {
  opacity: 0;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.large-image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image')];

// popup

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const imageName = document.querySelector('.image-name');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');
const imageIndex = document.querySelector('.index');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.left-arrow');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.right-arrow');

let index = 0; // will track our current image;

images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = `img/img${i+1}.png`;
    largeImage.src = path;
    imageName.innerHTML = path;
    imageIndex.innerHTML = `0${i+1}`;
    index = i;
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index > 0){
        updateImage(index - 1);
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(index < images.length - 1){
        updateImage(index + 1);
    }
})



const setPopupImage = index => {
  
  popup.classList.toggle('active');
}
setPopupImage(0);
```

I tried adding a new div class called “bk” inside each “gallery-image” class.  Also, in the CSS, I gave each “bk” a different background color in the CSS but this approach did not work. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't combine questions. Post a separate question for each.

Answer (score 0):

For animation:- please remove the transition property from CSS

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: cyan;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
}

.gallery {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90vh;
  max-width: 1600px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-image {
  width: 30%;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}



.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}




.popup.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup.active .close-btn,
.popup.active .image-name,
.popup.active .index,
.popup.active .large-image,
.popup.active .arrow-btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: turquoise;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


.image-name {
  opacity: 0;
}


.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-btn {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-arrow {
  left: 10px;
}

.right-arrow {
  right: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.index {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.large-image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

For Background:- please change the color Of the body(body {background: #000000;})